# how to submit multiple rows selected on row click to database in JqGrid?

Tags: select, jqgrid, row

i have a `JqGrid` and when I have to select multiple rows and click on a release button it need to send that columns to database. How can I achieve this? Do I have to send the data in `JSON` format ?

Comment: Could you explain more exactly what you want? What do you mean unter "release button"? Do you want send the information from some columns of selected rows to the web server? What should be done after receiving response from the server? The question where you should send data in JSON depends on your server components? Do you use ASMX web service on the server side, WCF, ASP.NET MVC or some PHP components?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes, you have to use JSON or XML any format will work . You can use JSON.stringify and use $.post those rows .