# jqGrid How to Delete Multiple Selected rows after submitting to a Database?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have this solution that submits multiple row data to a new database. But I want to append to the end of this action script  to delete the selected rows. How to properly add this function at the end after data has been submitted? I added a script but it does nothing.

Old code for button:

```
            jQuery("#minibutton").click( function(){

    var selectedrows = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
if(selectedrows.length) {
for(var i=0;i<selectedrows.length; i++) {

var selecteddatais = $("#list").jqGrid('getRowData',selectedrows[i]);
        var rows=JSON.stringify(selecteddatais)
        var postArray = {json:rows};

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "jsonsend.php",
   data: postArray,       
   dataType: "json",
   success: function () { jQuery("#list").jqGrid('delGridRow', id, options );

    } }); } } });
     });
```

Edit: My current try at solution

```
  $(function(){ 
  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'request.php',
    editurl: 'jqGridCrud.php',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    multiselect:true,
    multiboxonly:true,
    height: 450,
    width: 850,

    colNames:['id','Project', 'Assigned To','Assign Date','Check Date','Due Date','Attachments'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'id', index:'id', width:25}, 
      {name:'name', index:'name', width:250, align:'left',editable:true, editoptions:{
            size:60} }, 
      {name:'id_continent', index:'id_continent', width:55, align:'right',editable:true,edittype:'select', 
      editoptions:{value: "Henry:Henry; Ramon:Ramon; Paul:Paul" },mtype:'POST'  }, 

      {name:'lastvisit', index:'lastvisit', width:70, align:'right',formatter: 'date',srcformat:'yyyy-mm-dd',newformat: 'm-d-Y',editable:true, edittype: 'text',mtype:'POST' ,editoptions:{size:10, dataInit:function(elem){$(elem).datepicker({dateFormat:'m/d/yy'});}}} ,


      {name:'cdate', index:'cdate', width:70, align:'right',formatter: 'date',srcformat:'yyyy-mm-dd',newformat: 'm-d-Y', edittype: 'text',editable:true ,mtype:'POST' ,editoptions:{size:10, dataInit:function(elem){$(elem).datepicker({dateFormat:'m/d/yy'});}}} ,

      {name:'ddate', index:'ddate', width:70, align:'right',formatter: 'date',srcformat:'yyyy-mm-dd',newformat: 'm-d-Y',date:'true',editable:true, edittype: 'text',editoptions:{size:10, dataInit:function(elem){$(elem).datepicker({dateFormat:'m/d/yy'});}}} ,


      {name:'email', index:'email', width:70,align:'center',sortable:false,mtype:'POST' } 
    ],
    pager: '#pager',

    rowNum:20,
    rowList:[20,40,80],
    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Pending Assignments',


    ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {

    $(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid,
                        {width:450,Height:400,recreateForm:true,closeAfterEdit:true,
                         closeOnEscape:true,reloadAfterSubmit:false, modal:true,mtype:'post'});}


            });



       $("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", { add: false, search: false }, {}, {}, {
    url: "jsonsend.php",
    onclickSubmit: function (options, ids) {
        var $self = $(this), selectedrows = ids.split(","), selectedData = [], i,
            l = selectedrows.length;

        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            // fill array selectedData with the data from selected rows
            selectedData.push($self.jqGrid("getRowData", selectedrows[i]));
        }

        // the returned data will be combined with the default data
        // posted by delGridRow
        return {
            gridData: JSON.stringify(selectedData)
        }
    }
});


     });
```

jsonsend.PHP:

```
<?


    $database = "newhistoricform";
    $dbpassword = "pretty";
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";


// connect to the MySQL database server
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
@mysql_select_db($database,$con) or die("Error connecting to db.");




//First decode the array
$arr = $_POST["json"];
$decarr = json_decode($arr, true);
$count = count($decarr);


for ($x=0; $x < $count; $x++){
$newrec = $decarr; 
$id = $newrec['id']; 
$name = $newrec['name']; 
$id_continent = $newrec['id_continent']; 
$email = $newrec['email']; 
$lastvisit = $newrec['lastvisit']; 
$cdate = $newrec['cdate']; 
$ddate = $newrec['ddate']; 

}

// Create insert array
$values[] = "('".$id."', '".$name."', '".$id_continent."', '".$lastvisit."','".$cdate."','".$ddate."','".$email."' )";  





// Insert the records   

$sql = "INSERT INTO finish (id, name, id_continent, lastvisit,cdate,ddate, email)
VALUES ".implode(',', $values);

$result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());  


?>
```

Comment: No one can help? At least to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but I can't full follow you. First of all you fill grid with the data returned from the server (from `url:'request.php'`). The data are probably from the database. The `id` of the dataitems are filled too. If you correctly fill the grid then the contain of `id` attribute of every row (the rowid) and the content of `id` column will be the ids from the database.

To delete data in the database you need just have ids of rows which need be deleted. Instead of that you send *all data* from selected rows to the server. Why you do this? The server have already all the data? The only explanation would be that you need the information for concurrency control. OK, let us that the information is really needed be sent.

The main problem in your *existing code* seems to me the error in the logic: You get first **ids of all selected rows**. Then you make **separate Ajax call** for every id. Inside of `success` callback of the call (after **one** row was successfully deleted on the server side) you get **all selected rows** and **remove all selected rows from grid**. Because `success` will be called asynchronously you can remove some rows from the grid *before* you send the data to the server.

Moreover you use already [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow) method for editing of the rows. There are exist [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#delgridrow) method which send the list of selected ids to the server (default URL is `editurl: "sendyo.php"`) and delete the rows after successful conformation from the server side. You can use `delData` parameter (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties2)) to send any additional information to the list of ids. In the simplest form the code (the handle of `$("#minibutton").click` handle) could be like

```
$("#list").jqGrid("delGridRow", $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow"));
```

or, if you need send full content of all selected rows, then something like

```
var $grid = $("#list"),
    selectedrows = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow"),
    i,
    selectedData = [];

if (selectedrows.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < selectedrows.length; i++) {
        // fill array selectedData with the data from selected rows
        selectedData.push($grid.jqGrid("getRowData", selectedrows[i]));
    }
    $grid.jqGrid("delGridRow", $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow"), {
        delData: {
            gridData: JSON.stringify(selectedData)
        }
    });
}
```

The above code will send *tree* parameter to the server: `oper` with the value `"del"`, `id` with comma separated list of selected (deleted) rowids and `gridData` with the array of content of deleted rows serialized in JSON format.

You use `#minibutton` button currently. If you would use `navGrid` instead then you can simplify your code. You can use Delete button which calls `delGridRow` for you. You can use `onclickSubmit` callback to extend the posted data. If you don't need for example Add and Search buttons in the navigator bar you can use the code about as the following

```
$("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", { add: false, search: false }, {}, {}, {
    url: "jsonsend.php",
    onclickSubmit: function (options, ids) {
        var $self = $(this), selectedrows = ids.split(","), selectedData = [], i,
            l = selectedrows.length;

        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            // fill array selectedData with the data from selected rows
            selectedData.push($self.jqGrid("getRowData", selectedrows[i]));
        }

        // the returned data will be combined with the default data
        // posted by delGridRow
        return {
            gridData: JSON.stringify(selectedData)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: Which way you tried? Do you used `delGridRow` with `delData` or `onclickSubmit`? If no additional data are sent to the server that you did something wrong. Which code you used during your last attempts?

Comment: I edited question with current set-up. Two things. 1.The nav bar does not show at all now for some reason. 2. The data to be deleted should be deleted from the url:'jqGridCrud.php'. In xml array format. While that selected data is sent, in json string, to jsonsend.php connected to a different datatable. Is this possible?

Comment: I think that the last answer should work the way I want. The selected rows are deleted from the current table and the info will be sent in json.string to the jsonsend.php, correct? Thenthis is what i want. I currently have problem where nav grid not showing on my grid.

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: 1) I made typing error. One need include `"#pager"` as the first parameter of `navGrid` (see my modifications). You can use [ajaxDelOptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties2) option (you need place it on the same level where `onclickSubmit` callback) to set jQuery.ajax options like `dataType` or `contentType`. For example `ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json", dataType: "json" }`. It's difficult to answer you now because you removed your old manual call of jQuery.ajax. Do you can see now that `gridData` will be send?

Comment: reposted my old code. I have navgrid showing and I have tested it. It does send the data in json and the delete oper and id, together. But could kindly show how to send delete operation to editurl: 'jqGridCrud.php', while sending that deleted row data to  url: "jsonsend.php", in json. stringify . Thats all I need. Thank you so much

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: You are welcome! I'm not sure that I understand you correct. If the user click Delete button on navigator bar the request will be send to `editurl` per default. If you need so send it to another URL you can use `url` option like in the above example: `url: "jsonsend.php"`. I don't understand why you could need to make **two separate calls** with different URLs: `"jqGridCrud.php"` **and** `"jsonsend.php"` at one delete operation? If needed you can call internally any method *on the server side* to forward the information. I think that only **one** URL should be called.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30082/discussion-between-newhistoricform-and-oleg)

Comment: I understand. Could you please giveme some tips on how could I adjust my jsonsend.php(posted here) to 1. post the data to the "finish" table and 2. delete same rows from the table that the grid drew the data from? I really appreciate your help. i am a total noob and this is a life and death project. thank you

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: Sorry, but I am not a PHP developer. The SQL code could be additionally different depend on SQL server which you use. One can use [SQL SELECT INTO](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) construct to save some data *before* it will be deleted. So if you hold the data in `Demo` table you can make the same select which you use during filling of the grid but using WHERE id in (id1, id2, ...). You can use `SELECT INTO` construct to save the data to `finish` table from `Demo` table before deleting. You can place such operation and delete operation in one transaction.

Comment: @NewHistoricForm: In the case you can use standard jqGrid delete without any onclickSubmit bacsue you need only ids of rows which will be deleted.

Comment: So simple!! Thanks!!! Could you please give me a guidance on this problem:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641779/jqgrid-how-to-unformat-date-fields-and-post-in-format-yyyy-mm-dd-for-mysql-db)