# jqGrid How to unformat date fields and post in format yyyy-mm-dd for mysql DB?

Tags: jquery, mysql, jqgrid

butti have a big problem that i just havent been able to figure out. I have 3 date columns that can bbe edited but when i edit the row and don't update any of the date fields it posts in the new format that I set 'm-d-Y' instead of the source format for the server "yyyy-mm-dd. " How can I un-format these three fields before sending to the database if not edited at all? plesae note that the "asign date" has been changed by datepicker but other fields post as is if not edited.I do not want to change the back end php just the format on the fronend. Please any suggestions appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [serializeEditData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) callback you can modify the data which will be send from the server. The callback get as input parameter an object which properties are the parameters which will be send to the server. You can modify any from the property to change it. The callback can return either the modified object of the string.

The simplest example of the `serializeEditData` could be

```
serializeEditData: function (postData) {
    var partsOfDate = postdata.checkDate.split("/");
    if (partsOfDate.length === 3) {
        postdata.checkDate = partsOfDate[2] + "-" + partsOfDate[0] + "-" +
            partsOfDate[1];
    }
    return postdata;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much this works great! I appreciate it so much. Learning alot about jquery and jqgrid by you great help and answers. Thanks again.

Comment: please any suggestions for this [Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741078/how-to-view-a-list-of-contents-of-a-zip-file-from-link-on-jqgrid-row)

Comment: Can I get some suggestion for this problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778003/how-to-send-link-in-colmn-to-a-external-php-function-for-viewing-of-zip-contents)