# How to send link in colmn to a external PHP function for viewing of Zip contents in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I'm stuck. I have a grid that collects info about projects. When a project is entered it allows for upload of files that are then zipped and saved on the server in zip form with timestamp as name. The link is stored in the mysql database along with all of the info and then shown on the grid under "attachments" column for download. Now the problem is how to view the contents of that zip by either rollover or clicking opening window with a list of files or something before dowloading? Please any suggestions on how to begin would be appreciated.

I was thinking of an onclick function that leads to the php that will then show a list or something of the contents. But how to do that with jqgrid?Just need help leading  onclick of "files" to a external php function within jqgrid.Please

[image: Files]

jqgrid:

```
$(function(){ 
  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'request.php',
    editurl: "jqGridCrud.php",
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    height: 530,
    width: 850,
    scrollOffset:0,
    hidegrid: false,

    colNames:['id','Project', 'Assigned To','Assign Date','Check Date','Due Date','Attachments'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'id', index:'id', width:28}, 
      {name:'name', index:'name', width:250, align:'left',editable:true, editoptions:{
            size:60} }, 
      {name:'id_continent', index:'id_continent', width:55, align:'right',editable:true,edittype:'select', 
      editoptions:{value: "Henry:Henry; Ramon:Ramon; Paul:Paul" },mtype:'POST'  }, 

      {name:'lastvisit', index:'lastvisit', width:70, align:'right',formatter: 'date',srcformat:'yyyy-mm-dd',newformat: 'm/d/yy',editable:true, edittype: 'text',mtype:'POST' ,       editoptions:{size:10, dataInit:function(elem){$(elem).datepicker({dateFormat:'m/d/yy'});}}} ,


      {name:'cdate', index:'cdate', width:70, align:'right',formatter: 'date',srcformat:'yyyy-mm-dd',newformat: 'm/d/yy', edittype: 'text',editable:true ,mtype:'POST' ,editoptions:{size:10, dataInit:function(elem){$(elem).datepicker({dateFormat:'m/d/yy'});}}} ,

      {name:'ddate', index:'ddate', width:70, align:'right',formatter: 'date',srcformat:'yyyy-mm-dd',newformat: 'm/d/yy',date:'true',editable:true, edittype: 'text',editoptions:{size:10, dataInit:function(elem){$(elem).datepicker({dateFormat:'m/d/yy'});}}} ,


      {name:'file', index:'file', width:70,align:'center',sortable:false,mtype:'POST' } 
    ],
    pager: '#pager',

    rowNum:23,
    rowList:[23,40,80],
    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Current Assignments',


    ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {

    $(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid,
                        {width:550,Height:550,recreateForm:true,closeAfterEdit:true,
                         closeOnEscape:true,reloadAfterSubmit:true, modal:true,mtype:'post',top:350,left: 30});}


            });

 jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.nav, {
        deltitle: 'Remove Completed Project',

    }); 

    $("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", { add: false, search: false, refresh:false,edit:false });
});
```

XML loaded for Attachments column in a html "link" like this last  at the bottom:

```
<row id="2">
<cell>2</cell>
<cell>New Promotional Website for New Machine</cell>
<cell> Ramon</cell>
<cell>2013-05-08</cell>
<cell>2013-05-27</cell>
<cell>2013-06-06</cell>
<cell><a href=/uploads/1369072920.zip>Files</a></cell>
</row>
```

Comment: To be able to view content of zipped file web browser should have access to *local* files on the computer. It's not allowed because of security reasons. You can probably suggest some solutions to do this, but the solution will work only on *specific* web browser. So I think that you formulate the problem in a wrong way.

Comment: @Oleg I understand but i want it where when user clicks on the link that they will be sent to a php function that will show them a list of the files contained in the linked zip folder.That zip folder is stored on the server in an "uploads" folder. I need guidence on how to send user to that php function that will open up a window that displays a list of contained files.

Comment: If the zip file already uploaded on the server you can implement preview in your server code. I am not PHP developer and can't help you here. In .NET which I personally use there are classes which allows to work with zip files. See `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` for example. I think you should ask pure PHP question about reading directory of ZIP file in PHP, but probably [the link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_zip.asp) forward you in correct direction.

Comment: @Oleg Sounds good. But I just went the simple route. i just sent the zip to google docs for viewing before opening.could you take alook at printing a jqgrid grid problem I have , please? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803329/how-to-print-jqgrid-with-onclick-print-function-on-navbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply send the link to google docs and it opens the zip with all files shown without downloading.

```
}
$filepath = addslashes("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.dope.com/uploads/".$archiveName.""); 
print_r($filepath);
```